# DocuSign SOAP based API with DocuSign Account ID

Tags: docusignapi

I have been using DocuSign SOAP Based API calls to create and send envelopes and am using legacy authentication method in which I can specify email address and password of the DocuSign user who is going to create envelopes.

One our client have multiple DocuSign account with the same user. When I setup an authentication header thru the SOAP based API call, I do not have a way to specify which account I am making API calls against.

How do I make sure that I am making API calls against the specific account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways of accomplishing this.

1) You can make a getlogin call to retrieve a list of the logins associated with an account and use the default.

OR

2) Instead of supplying the email address for the user you can supply the API UserName in the login headers, which is a unique number for that user. This can be retrieved from the API and Keys or Users section if they're using the New DocuSign Experience, or through the user Permission section if still using Classic.

While the ApiUserName or email address is usually supplied in the authentication header, the ID for the account is in the XML body for the call. the combination of apiUserName and AccountId should be sufficient in picking a specific user, even if they have the same email address associated with multiple accounts.

Comment: In my case, the API username is the same for this user in both accounts. I will have to get the account id from the login request and then add that account id in the XML body request.